# React components library + SASS modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm starting to work on a react components library and I want to reuse some SCSS code we share with other non-react projects.

To accomplish that, I'm trying to use [SASS modules](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/) into react component.

The simple use case works fine, but I'm creating a components library and I need to have several style combinations for some components like the button.

Right now, I'm having an issue with the `Button` component. Component is pretty simple, but it has 3 different `variant` values.

Here is the `Button.tsx` file:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Button.module.scss";

type Variant = "default" | "primary" | "tertiary";

interface Props {
  children: String;
  variant: Variant;
}

export const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, variant }) => {
  return <button className={`${styles.button} ${variant}`}>{children}</button>;
};
```

and here is the `Button.module.scss` file:

```scss
.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;

  &.default {
    background-color: green;
  }
  &.primary {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

What I expect, is to have a green button if I use the component like `<Button variant="default">I'm green</Button>`, but instead I'm getting the grey button.

Here is a live example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-varahamihira-topfyf?file=/src/components/Button.tsx)

I'm stuck on this, could somebody help me to apply different styles based on prop values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button className={`${styles.button} ${styles[variant]}`}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `classnames` npm library.

```
import cn from 'classnames';

<button className={cn(styles.button, styles[variant])}>
```